# What is meant by k-anonymity and l-diversity, and what is difference between them?

Tags: java, algorithm

What is meant by k-anonymity and l-diversity, and what is difference between them? This concept is used in the [following IEEE paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5645011).

Comment: For explanations of k-anonymity and l-diversity, see [this article](https://missingdata.wordpress.com/2007/08/23/k-anonymity-and-l-diversity/). (I found this at the end of a Google search for `k-anonymity l-diversity`.)

Comment: how on earth was this not a real question?  is my answer not a real answer?  how can "what are X and Y and how do they differ?" be misunderstood?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

an anonymised dataset contains multiple fields that can be used to identify someone (eg. age, sex, location).  even if one field is not unique, a combination of them may be (eg. there may be only 1 male aged 54 in squatsville).  k-anonymity greater than 1 means that even with all fields you don't identify a single person - you identify "k" people.

but that's not enough, because all k people identified by a distinct set of the different fields might be associated with the same value - if there are 10 different 54 year-old males in squatsville and they all wear ladies clothes, then you know that bob, who is 54 and lives in squatsville, wears ladies clothes.  so you need diversity within the group identified by the fields.  l-diversity means that the group contains "l" (the letter L, not the digit 1) different values.

[no offense intended - seriously - to cross-dressers.  i just wanted something mildly amusing that wasn't, well, cancer...]

and a reference - http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs656/reading/ldiversity.pdf

Comment: +1 for the vivid and life-like examples :)

Comment: Good clear explanation, but I have a question. If there are 3 Bobs who  wear women clothing, 4 who wear women underwear, and the rest who wear only mens-wear, that would give an l-diversity of 3?

Comment: [assuming you're serious] well, you wouldn't know they were called bob.  but if there were 10 males aged 54 in squatsville and they covered 3 different categories then l is 3 (see "principle 2" in section 4.1 of the paper i just linked to).

Comment: Ah yes, I read 'Bob' as being one of the identifying fields. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I laughed so hard, also very well explained!